# Suppress questions by apt-get

Tags: debian, apt

I need to install a package in a script.
This process needs to write over some already existing configuration files.
Right now even though run with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and `--force-yes -y`, apt still asks for user input:

```
Configuration file `/etc/init.d/nginx'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
     D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** nginx (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

How to make this **completely** uninteractive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `yes | program` or `dpkg-reconfigure debconf`

Comment: `yes` is dangerous. At least make that `yes n`, which is a bit less dangerous.